# How do you translate this for loop into mathematics

Tags: math

I'm trying to solve what seems to be a simple math problem. I can write the problem as a for loop, but I'm not sure how to translate it into an equation. Can anyone help?

```
x = 10;
for(int i=0; i<3000; i++)
{
    x = x^2
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified, the above is psuedocode. This is not for a programming problem so I'm not worried about overflows :) I'm actually trying to solve a math problem by hand. I know how to express the problem in code but not in mathematics.

Thanks for everyone's help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

x^(2^3000) where ^ means to the power of

Comment: All the x^6000 answers are wrong.  It's true that (x^2)^3000 == x^6000.  However, that is not what the loop is saying.  I'm surprised (and rather disappointed) that you are in the minority in reading it correctly.

Answer (score 6):

You provided code, and are asking us to provide the mathematical equivalent -- so I'm going to take your code literally, and assume it's a C-like language.

In that environment, ^ is the bitwise XOR operator. So after the loop x = 10, since it was XOR-ed with a constant 2 (toggling the next-to-LSB bit) an even number of times.

Or was this merely pseudocode -- did you really mean exponentiation?

Comment: P.S. Was I the only one to actually compile this and see what it did?

Comment: I think you deserve a certain amount of props for mentioning that ^ is not exponentiation in C.  I think most C coders wouldn't have had to compile it to figure that out though. ;)  Also, I will state for the record that you did answer before the OP clarified that he was using pseudocode.  I will also state for the record that using C's for loop and braces is not the best choice for PSEUDOcode, which makes your confusion all the more understandable.

Answer (score 6):

The mathematical name for the class of problem you have given is [recurrence relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation). A recurrence relation defines a sequence A<sub>n</sub> in terms of the preceding terms A<sub>n-1</sub>, A<sub>n-2</sub>, etc. In your case,

> A<sub>n</sub> = A<sub>n-1</sub><sup>2</sup>

As other answers have shown, creating a [closed-form solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_solution) for your given example is straightforward. Solving a recurrence relation can quickly become much more difficult with seemingly simple changes to the relation:

> A<sub>n</sub> = A<sub>n-1</sub><sup>2</sup> + c

Such a nonlinear recurrence relation may not even have a closed-form solution, depending on the value of *c*. (Incidentally, when used with complex numbers the above recurrence relation is at the heart of the [Mandelbrot set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set).)

Answer (score 4):

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    x = x^p
```

is equivalent to:

```
x = x^(p^n)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something (original value of 10 in your case) will be squared 3000 times.

Answer (score -3):

Given it's a constant, how about just

```
x = 10000000... (etc.)
```

But I suspect you want something a bit more intensional:

```
x = 10^6000
```

Or even more:

```
x = (10^2)^3000
```

Or (if you allow slightly looser notation):

```
x = (10^2) ... ^2
```

with a horizontal "} 3000" under the "...".